# Programable way to determine the current double-tap speed setting in Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, touch

I'm implementing a touch interface for Windows in Win32 (C++). I would like to find out the current double-tap (not double-click) speed that Windows is set to. I know Windows is set to accept double-taps as various messages (depending on whether you're using gestures or not), but I'm looking at doing something a bit more advanced. I'm thus handling `WM_TOUCH` messages. I'm hoping there's a better (i.e. future-proof) way than rummaging through the registry to find that setting. MSDN wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a specific double-touch notification, I suspect the application is expected to decided for itself if a `WM_TOUCH` is part of a double tap.  The most common way to do that is probably to check the timing between touches.  By default, I'd imagine that most apps use the mouse double-click setting as the default.

[GetDoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646258%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704137.aspx), the double-tap and double-click times are different. I really appreciate the link to the double-click function, though

Comment: After much searching and waiting, I guess you must be right. Looks like I'll either have to make up my own timeout, or use `GetDoubleClickTime`, as suggested. Thanks for your patience, Adrian.

Comment: @Warpspace: The diagram you linked to suggests that `ISG_DBLTAP` and `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` are generated at the same time, in other words: they use the same timeout. The only difference here is that the synthesized `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is postponed until the pen has been lifted off the surface.

Comment: @IInspectable: That doesn't mean that `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` from a mouse and one synthesized from touch input are using the same timing thresholds... just that the application receives the same message.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was referring to the diagram from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704137.aspx), which suggests that the timeouts were the same. While the textual description acknowledges, that there are no guarantees with respect to ordering or timing, the diagrams disagree with that, and paint a criminally misleading picture.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't disagree with your point concerning the diagram, however I think you are misunderstanding my point.  When you click a mouse, click event is generated at time 0, a second click causes the time to be compared to interval A (`GetDoubleClickTime`), if it is less a double click event is generated.  A second click is generated.  When you tap, click event is generated at time 0.  A second tap causes the time to be compared to interval B, if it is less then both double tap and double click events are generated.

Comment: This implies that for tap processing, both `ISG_DBLTAP` and `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` are dependent on the same interval, interval B.  It does not require that the interval used to generate `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` during tap processing and the interval used to generate `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` during mouse processing are the same, it is possible that interval A != interval B.

Comment: Finally, the text also says that mouse input will generate tap messages.  But that would be based on mouse timing, i.e. interval A.